# What are the ways to optimize browsing performance over slow internet connections?

Tags: networking

I'm not talking about gaining faster internet speeds, but more of a fair distribution of available bandwidth between all applications that request a network connection. On a household laptop, not a production server. As of right now, whenever I try to watch a movie or download some updates, it takes up all the bandwidth to itself and I can't browse web while it does that. I need a Linux built-in solution, without installing an additional application. Maybe fine tuning timeouts and whatnot. I'm guessing a lot of this can be done with `sysctl` , but I have no idea what set of parameters would yield the best result. The bandwidth I'm talking about is within 1-12 Mbit/s

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu, I had some success with `wondershaper`. Although it lacks fine grained control, it should do more or less what you are looking for. From the man page:

> This  manual page documents briefly the wondershaper script.  This manual page was written
> for the Debian distribution because the original script does not have a manual page.
> wondershaper is a traffic shaping script  that  provides  low  latency,  prioritizes  bulk
> transfers  below  normal  web  traffic,  prioritizes  interactive  shells above normal web
> traffic, and attempts to prevent upload and download traffic from affecting  each  other's
> ack   packets.    Put  simply,  the  wondershaper  makes  your  internet  connection  more
> "responsive"

Especially if you're not too much into tuning, this will probably give you a workable set-up.

Comment: Actually, I like tuning a lot. That's how I ended up having a Linux-powered laptop =)

Comment: wondershaper has a lot of optional configurations available and is simply a shell script setting up [tc](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html) rules. Also be sure to use the one available on [github (currently 1.4.1)](https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper) not for example the [original one still shipped by Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wondershaper), and really not up to date.

Comment: To add to the above, you should read (after installing) the files in `/usr/share/doc/wondershaper/README.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/wondershaper/README.Debian.gz`. There's some helpful information in there.